# Stop tracking an entire repository to delete local files

Tags: git, github

A simple question:

How do I stop tracking an entire repository and delete all the local files safely?
I have a remote repository, which, after a few commits, I decide to leave alone. But I also don't want it to clog up my disk space, so I want to wipe it off my local disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the repo was this for example

```
git clone git://github.com/antirez/redis.git
```

You can remove the local files by simply deleting the folder

```
rm -r redis
```

This will leave the remote files untouched.

Comment: That was easy. I didn't know just deleting all the files worked. Thanks! I'll accept you answer in 2 minutes.